# Modifying simple VBA script to account for a different match?

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm using this function:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = LCase(Cells(I, "A").Value)
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(LCase(Cells(J, "C").Value), v) > 0 Then ' What to do here?
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

To match a column of image names to the items they belong to in another column. This works great except in one case:

> If the item number includes a *"-SET2"* string in the item name -- so **MCR7009A-SET2** instead of **MCR7009A** -- the images that don't have SET2 in the file name won't end up as a match. This causes many images to be ignored.

How can I account for the possibility of *"-SET2"* being in the item name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for -set2 on the end of v, if it is there, strip it out

```
Sub Test()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = LCase(Cells(I, "A").Value)

        'Check for -set2 on the end of v, if it is there, strip it out
        If Right(v, 5) = "-set2" Then
            v = Left(v, Len(v) - 5)
        End If

        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(LCase(Cells(J, "C").Value), v) > 0 Then ' What to do here?
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2, 2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Unfortunately it still isn't matching correctly?

Comment: Is the -SET2 in the column A or C?

Comment: It's in Column A -- I need to create matches even if the image name doesn't include the "SET-2" does that make sense? So if the image name (which are all in column C) is MCR7009A-LEG.jpg I need it to still match the item number in Col. A

Comment: I think so. So we need to take it out of the name. Let me modify.

Comment: Exactly that's what I need to do, just so it matches.

Comment: Changed it to take the -set2 off the right side of the string.

Comment: Glad to be able to help.